# Unable to run Bash Script from PHP Code out of HTML Page

Tags: php, html, linux, nginx, scripting

having a small issue here.
Already tried many approaches I found on the web to resolve this, didn't get it to work so far.

I am trying to execute a server-side Linux Bash Script when a Button on a static HTML side is clicked.
It just doesn't work.

My setup is a nginx webserver running on ubuntu, got a static HTML page with PHP code within it:

Ubuntu Version: 18.04.2 LTS (Bionic Beaver) /
Linux Version: 5.4.0-42-generic /
Nginx Version: nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu) /
PHP Version: 7.4.11

Bash Script is stored in the same folder as the index.html for the website (/var/www/website).
For testing purposes, gave ownership if the script file to the user www-data and even gave full access to all users to the file (chmod 777 script.sh),
script file is also definitely executalble.

Also this works perfectly fine:
`sudo -u www-data php -r "shell_exec('bash script.sh');"`

PHP Code within the HTML file:

```
<?php
    shell_exec('bash script.sh)';
?>
```

Tested with some echo's that this part gets executed. Also looks good.

But the script is never running ..

Would very much appreciate any hints, as you may be able to tell, my web skills are as bad as my scripting skills ;)

Thanks a lot and best regards

Juls

Comment: You have to put the php code into a .php file not in a .html, but if it is ok, then check if the `script.sh` file has the `#!/bin/bash` in the first line. Perhaps only `shell_exec('./script.sh)';` is enough. Or try to specify the FULL path of the script like `shell_exec('bash /var/www/website/script.sh)';`

Comment: @hlorand thanks a lot for your hints! I tried putting the php code in a .php file and included the file html code, didn't get this to work, but I'll keep trying stuff in this direction. The script.sh is definitely OK :)

Answer (score 0):

Is the shellscript executable without sudo? Maybe try

```
chmod +x script.sh
```